# How to ignore validation in HDIV when integrating with primefaces datatable component

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-extensions, hdiv

I am using Primefaces Datatable component. This data table component creates a hidden field dynamically on the browser.

```
<input type="hidden" id="formId:activitydescription_selection" name="formId:activitydescription_selection" autocomplete="off" value="" />
```

The Primefaces datatable code is as follows

```
<p:dataTable  id="activitydescription" var="type"
            value="#{activityBean.activityList}" rows="#{activityBean.rowNo}" rowKey="#{type.activitySchemeId}"
            selection="#{activityBean.activityDTO}"
            emptyMessage="No value found with given criteria"
            paginatorPosition="bottom" sortMode="single" paginator="#{empty activityBean.activityList ? 'false':'true' }"
            dynamic="true"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
            rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
```

Now when the page is submitted HIDV thinks the hidden field which is created dynamically on the browser is a case of hacking thereby redirecting to error page with the console log as

```
org.hdiv.logs.Logger log INVALID_PARAMETER_NAME;/hseadmin/pages/secured/admin/Layout.xhtml;**formId:activitydescription_selection**;;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1;anonymous
```

In my hdiv-config.xml file i have modified the file so that HDIV ignore thi validation where this field occurs

```
<hdiv:paramsWithoutValidation>
         <hdiv:mapping url=".*"  parameters="formId:activitydescription_selection"/>
        </hdiv:paramsWithoutValidation>
```

But no luck still the same console error and HDIV is redirecting to error page.
Can someone help me out on how to avoid these validations on HDIV?

Comment: What is the advantage of using hdiv for this? Jsf is a ui framwork that has serverside counterparts of all ui components and checks if what is posted matches with what can be post in terms of availbity of fields and even values of fields (e.g. selects)

Comment: @Kukeltje: Can you suggest how do i avoid 10 owasp errors in primefaces.

Comment: Start by posting a new question with enough detail

Answer (score 0):

try..

```
<property name="userStartParameters">  
<list>
  <value>hidden1Name</value>
  <value>hidden2Name</value>
</list>
</property>
```

Comment: are you suggesting that i put the above sugestion in hdiv-confg.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

HDIV doesn't support the Primefaces components, only standard JSF components like `<h:dataTable>`.

http://www.hdiv.org/hdiv-documentation-single/doc.html

Comment: Thanks @gillarramendi for the making the picture crystal clear.So now we can look for alternatives.Any plans to release a version of HDIV compatible with Primefaces components any time soon.