# can we avoid <input type="hidden".. from primefaces datatable component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, primefaces-extensions

We are using Primefaces Datatable component where the values are coming from a database.
in our xx.xhtml file below code is present

```
<p:dataTable  id="activitydescription" var="type"
            value="#{activityBean.activityList}" rows="#{activityBean.rowNo}" rowKey="#{type.activitySchemeId}"
            selection="#{activityBean.activityDTO}"
            emptyMessage="No value found with given criteria"
            paginatorPosition="bottom" sortMode="single" paginator="#{empty activityBean.activityList ? 'false':'true' }"
            dynamic="true"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
            rowIndexVar="rowIndex"> ........
```

Now when this page is rendered on the browser we have seen a hidden field is created as below..

```
<input type="hidden" id="formId:activitydescription_selection" name="formId:activitydescription_selection" autocomplete="off" value="" /></div><script id="formId:activitydescription_s" type="text/javascript">
```

The field is created dynamically when the datatable component is rendered on browser.
So is there any way we can avoid this hidden field to be created.?

I hope i have rephrased my query very clearly.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you try to rephrase the question? I don't understand it at least. You want to acces the value of the activitydescription:Selection field?

Comment: There is one major question in there that you should ask yourself... Please do ;-)

Comment: Please enhance your question and refer to you hdiv post

Comment: What exactly is your problem with that hidden field? Don't you want the `p:dataTable` being able to prepare values for `selection` attribute? I really don't understand starters asking "How to avoid X" where X is fundamental for the functioning.

Comment: @BalusC: the new super duper framework he uses chockes on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298563/how-to-ignore-validation-in-hdiv-when-integrating-with-primefaces-datatable-comp Not sure about some of the so called advantages of this framework if you already use jsf and 'think' about what you develop

Comment: :o Well, Joy, those are perhaps enlightenend readings: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7722159, http://stackoverflow.com/q/23167104, http://stackoverflow.com/q/4421839 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/5475564

Comment: @thanks BalusC for the links.

Comment: Yes @Kukeltje you are right ..was trying to integrate HDIV filter with Primeface and then this problem came.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, this field is needed for the component to function correctly. But.... You can always download the source, implement a different solution and file a patch...

Comment: if answers are 'good', please accept them and upvote if it was realy helpful. That is good practice in StackOverflow